# PHP Str_replace for echo function

Tags: php, function, echo, str-replace

The following function is part of code written into the core of a plugin I am reverse engineering. The problem with it is that I need to do an str_replace on it and I cannot because it is already set to echo.

The function is.

```
function similar_posts($args = '') {
    echo SimilarPosts::execute($args);
}
```

I call it in my pages using `similar_posts()`, but what I really need to do in my theme is call `$related = similar_posts()`, however that function is set to echo. How do I change that.

I tried this.

```
 function get_similar_posts($args = '') {
        SimilarPosts::execute($args);
    }
```

But that did not produce any results.

Comment: try `return SimilarPosts::execute($args);`, then you can do the `$related = similar_posts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) instead of echo.

So that you have:

```
 return SimilarPosts::execute($args);
```

instead of:

```
 echo SimilarPosts::execute($args);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_similar_posts($args = '') {
    return (SimilarPosts::execute($args));
}
```

Comment: return is a keyword, not a function. Please don't wrap whatever being returned in `()`.

Comment: It always looks wrong to me when it's not, and I don't see any reason why I shouldn't.

Comment: It's prone to future errors, if you (as an example) would like to return a variable my reference but wrap it in `()`, it will **not** work.

Comment: PHP's own manual advises against returning by reference unless you absolutely have to anyway.  Objexts are always passed by reference these days, and things like arrays utilise Copy On Write so there's rarely anything to be gained by returning by reference.

Comment: PHP's own manual also advises using return without `()`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the value `SimilarPosts::execute ($args)` returns, you'll need to use the keyword 'return' inside your `get_similar_posts`.

```
function get_similar_posts ($args = '') {
  return SimilarPosts::execute($args);
}
```

---

If you are unable to change the definition of `get_similar_posts` there are ways to snatch the content printed by `similar_posts` even though it's "set to echo".

This can be accompished by using the [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) available in PHP.

```
function echo_hello_world () {
  echo "hello world";
}

$printed_data = ""; 

ob_start (); 
{
  echo_hello_world (); 

  $printed_data = ob_get_contents (); 
}
ob_end_clean (); 

echo "echo_hello_world () printed '$printed_data'\n";
```

output

```
echo_hello_world () printed 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the function inside another in which you use [output buffering.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: The OP is able to change the code as he is reveries engineering it. SO buffer control is the wrong way I reckon.

Answer (score 1):

Done it..

```
function get_similar_posts($args = '') {
    return SimilarPosts::execute($args);
}
```

and on the page `get_similar_posts();`

Should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

`return` from the function:

```
function get_similar_posts($args = '') {
     return  SimilarPosts::execute($args);
}
```